# Excel VBA copy Run-Time error '1004'

Tags: vba, excel

I can't figure out what's wrong with my VBA:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Sheets("Opgave").Select
    Range("F9:G14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Reserve").Select
    Range("E3").Select    
End Sub
```

Excel says `Range("F9:G14").Select` is wrong!

Answer (score 4):

<s>You need to `Activate` the sheet, because `Range` is implicitly referring to the *active* worksheet, and you're wrongly assuming `Select`ing something will necessarily `Activate` it.</s>

I've executed your code with `"Sheet1"` and `"Sheet2"` without any error being thrown, "Sheet1!F9:G14" selected for copy and "Sheet2!E3" selected, which seems to be what this code wants to achieve.

Still, I'd like to say...

#### Avoid problems, avoid `Select` and `Activate` in VBA code.

Sheets have a `CodeName` property that you can change from, say, `Sheet1` to `OpgaveSheet`, or `Sheet2` to `ReserveSheet`. Then this code is valid:

```
OpgaveSheet.Range("F9:G14").Copy ReserveSheet.Range("E3")
```

The `Name` of a worksheet is the text that's displayed in the tab for it in Excel. You can also use that to get a reference to a worksheet:

```
Dim opgaveSheet As Worksheet
Set opgaveSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Opgave")

Dim reserveSheet As Worksheet
Set reserveSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reserve")
```

And when you want to work with a specific range, keep a reference to it instead of `Select`ing it and working with the `Selection`:

```
Dim source As Range
Set source = opgaveSheet.Range("F9:G14")

Dim destination As Range
Set destination = reserveSheet.Range("E3")

source.Copy destination
```

Code that doesn't constantly interact with worksheets (via `Select` and `Activate`) is going to perform better, will be easier to follow, debug and maintain, and will be much less error-prone.